# How to linearly interpolate in Excel as simply as Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vba, interpolation

**User case**

I need to manage a forward curve (a timeseries of prices) in Excel, providing values for dates where available, and filling all other dates with a linear interpolation between previous and next known values. I want to add new values when they appear in the market (i.e. a new pivot point), but also remove values as quotes become obsolete over time, reverting to the interpolated value instead.

**Example**

In Pandas, it is as simple as using `interpolate()`

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame(data = nan,
                  columns=["some_data"], 
                  index=pd.date_range("20220101", periods=10))


df.loc['2022-01-01', 'some_data'] = 10
df.loc['2022-01-10', 'some_data'] = 100
print(df)
df.interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)
print(df)
df.some_data.plot()

#adding a couple pivots in the curve
df.some_data = nan
df.loc['2022-01-01', 'some_data'] = 10
df.loc['2022-01-04', 'some_data'] = 25
df.loc['2022-01-08', 'some_data'] = 110
df.loc['2022-01-10', 'some_data'] = 100
print(df)
df.interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)
print(df)
df.some_data.plot()
```

As I add two pivot points, the dataframe updates its values as follows:

```
            intial_state     interp1  add_2_pivots  interp2
1/1/2022    10               10       10            10
1/2/2022    NaN              20       NaN           15
1/3/2022    NaN              30       NaN           20
1/4/2022    NaN              40       25            25
1/5/2022    NaN              50       NaN           46.25
1/6/2022    NaN              60       NaN           67.5
1/7/2022    NaN              70       NaN           88.75
1/8/2022    NaN              80       110           110
1/9/2022    NaN              90       NaN           105
1/10/2022   100              100      100           100
```

[image: Curve before and after adding pivots]

**Question**

Now, bearing in mind that:

1. I would like to avoid cell formulas (bound to lead to problems in
   production)
2. FORECAST seems to only know regressions
3. I'd rather avoid the VBA function rabbit hole if I can...

***Is there a similarly simple way to achieve this in Excel?***

Thank you,

Comment: Do you just need the graph? Your Python code using `interpolate` just shows how it's plotting a line graph. Or do you actually need to be able to enter a date and find the value whether interpolated or actual?

Comment: Graph was only for illustration purpose. It's the values i'm after. I'll edit to add the content of the dataframe, for the sake of clarity. Thanks,

Comment: Used forecast() to predict future values from a string of numbers - failures after time in service. worked well.